# Separating a pandas data frame based on whether the string-valued entry in a specified column contains a substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a', 'b', 'c','d','e'], 'description':['vim2tests','vim2trial','vim3tests','vim3zip', 'vim4trial'], 'count':[4,5,6,7,8]})
```

And I am trying to separate into 3 data frames containing the rows where the 'description' entry contains the 'vim2', 'vim3', 'vim4' substring.

Is there an efficient way to do this? I could implement a for loop to find the indexes for the rows I want, but that is not efficient at all and I am struggling to see how to do this a better way.

Comment: Do you actually just need three dataframes  as output or more?

Comment: @DavideBrex In my data set there would be 10. But I am interested in knowing the solution for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, just create a conditional column to `groupby` using `str.extract`

we can hold the dataframes in a dictionary.

```
dfs = {group : data.drop('key',1) for group,data in 
                 df.assign(key=df['description'].str.extract('(vim\d+)'))\
                           .groupby('key')
}
```

---

```
print(dfs['vim3'])
  name description  count
2    c   vim3tests      6
3    d     vim3zip      7
```

---

```
print(dfs.keys())

dict_keys(['vim2', 'vim3', 'vim4'])
```

or a much simplier solution by anky -

```
dfs = dict(tuple(
           df.groupby(df['description'].str.extract('(vim\d+)'
                                        ,expand=False))
         ))
```

Or:

```
dict(iter(df.groupby(df['description'].str.extract('(vim\d+)',expand=False)))
```

---

```
print(dfs)

{'vim2':   name description  count
 0    a   vim2tests      4
 1    b   vim2trial      5,
 'vim3':   name description  count
 2    c   vim3tests      6
 3    d     vim3zip      7,
 'vim4':   name description  count
 4    e   vim4trial      8}
```